# Passing data-id1 and data-id2 values to a modal in PHP using AJAX and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, modalpopupextender

I want to pass double id (data-id1 and data-id2) values in modal.
when i try to do so i get only on data-id1 being pass the data-id2 doesn't get pass,
so the Modal popups with an empty table.

[image]

this is my view before triggering the modal

[image]

this is my HTML query:

```
<a class="openModal" data-id1="<?php echo htmlentities($result->requestitem_item); ?>" data-id2="<?php echo htmlentities($result->request_NUMBER); ?>" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal"><input style="font-size:25px" type="text" name="itemserialno[]" value="" required>
```

and this is my script:

```
<script>
  $('.openModal').click(function(){
      var id1 = $(this).attr('data-id1');
      var id2 = $(this).attr('data-id2');
      $.ajax({url:"modalajax.php?id1=&id2="+(id1&id2),cache:false,success:function(result){
          $(".modal-content").html(result);
      }});
  });
</script>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" style="width:50%">
    <div class="modal-content">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Below is my Modal $_GET trigger:

```
$ID=$_GET['id1']??'';
$ID1=$_GET['id2']??'';

$sql = "SELECT * from  itemTABLE where (itemTABLE_item ='$ID1' and itemTABLE_requestNUMBER ='$ID2') and itemTABLE_acceptance != 'Reject' " ;
```

Comment: Check the actual HTML output. I would guess that something in the PHP statement coming out of `htmlentities()` in `data-id1` is breaking the HTML syntax, so `data-id2` is malformed.

Comment: Also, in the AJAX request you only populate the value of the `id2` querystring argument with the bitwise AND result of `id1&id2`. I'm guessing the URL should instead be: `"modalajax.php?id1=" + id1 + "&id2=" + id2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be like this

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "modalajax.php?id1=" + id1 + "&id2=" + id2,
    cache: false,
    success: function(result) {
        $(".modal-content").html(result);
    }
});
```